# Compare two lists - If any objects property in one list have changed or a new object in list been added, return that object

Tags: c#, linq, list, compare

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Product 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two lists of these:

```
var oldList = new List<Product>(){
        new Product(){
          Id = "1", Quantity = 1
        }
      };

var newList = new List<Product>(){
        new Product(){
          Id = "1", Quantity = 5
        }
      };
```

How can I compare these two list and return a single Product-object of the item in the `newList` that have changed. Like the code-scenario above I want to return a Product-object with the values `Id = "1", Quantity = 5`

The other scenario looks like this:

```
var oldList = new List<Product>(){
        new Product(){
          Id = "1", Quantity = 1
        }
      };

var newList = new List<Product>(){
        new Product(){
          Id = "1", Quantity = 1
        },
        new Product(){
          Id = "2", Quantity = 1
        }
      };
```

If a new item been added to the `newList` then I want to return that item(product-object with Id="2")

Comment: `var diffList = oldList.Where(o => !newList.Any(n => n.Id == o.Id))
            .Union(newList.Where(n => !oldList.Any(o => n.Id == o.Id)));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should implement equality comparer to compare that 2 product items are equal:

```
class ProductEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Quantity == y.Quantity;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

        return product.Id.GetHashCode() ^ product.Quantity.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Except` function to get the difference between 2 lists:

```
var result = newList.Except(oldList, new ProductEqualityComparer() );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = newList.Except(oldList);
```

but you have first to implement the `IEquatable` interface for the `Product` class.

```
public class Product : IEquatable<Product> 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Product product)
    {
        if (product == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (Id == product.Id) && (Quantity == product.Quantity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, so you dont have to use Except is to do it using Linq to Object like this:

```
public List<MyItems> GetItemsFromANotInThatAreNotInB(List<MyItems> A, List<MyItems> B)
{
    return (from b in B
            where !(from a in A select a.Id).Contains(b.Id)
            select b).ToList();
}
```